# Drag and drop an item from one recyclerview (listview) into another recyclerview (listview)

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement that need to drag an item from one recyclerview into another recyclerview.

I found some some of the useful resource as 
with the help of [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html)

Also find a library to drag and drop in android [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.u6h1s613n).

While implementation, am able to drag the item view along with the pointer(finger) on the screen, but not able success to achieve my requirement.

Please share me if you have any previous experience on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple list view drag and drop you can refer this 
https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

**Features**

- Re-order items in a list, grid or board by dragging and dropping with
  nice animations.
- Add custom animations when the drag is starting and ending.
- Get a callback when a drag is started and ended with the position.
- Disable and enable drag and drop

Simple implementation of Drag and Drop in RecyclerView is given below

https://github.com/AleBarreto/DragRecyclerView

Comment: Hello Vinay Jayaram, Thanks for giving replay,. 
Its for only inside the single RecyclerView. But I need between two recyclerViews.

Comment: @RameshSwamy Updated my answer above

Comment: yaaa, this [link]( https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) what exactly matches to my requirement.Thanks a lot Vinay.