# Is it possible to drag an item outside of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I need to somehow notify `RecyclerView` when I drag and drop an item from another `RecyclerView` onto it.

- Is it possible?
- Or should I use classic [Drag and drop framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)?

[image: Drag and drop an item to another RecyclerView]

`RecyclerView` with blue items is in one fragment and `RecyclerView` with red items is in another fragment.

I also tried using [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html#onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(android.view.View)) but it's [onMove()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onMove(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) method from [ItemTouchHelper.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html) is not called while moving with item outside
from `RecyclerView`.

```java
private class CustomItemTouchCallback extends Callback {

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeMovementFlags(UP|DOWN|START|END, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Move item  from:" + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + " to: " + target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Moved item  from:" + fromPos + " to: " + toPos + " x: " + x + " y: " + y);
        super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583571/drag-and-drop-an-item-from-one-recyclerview-listview-into-another-recyclerview), but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @maratus i wanted to use the same functionality did u find any solution to it?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: Since RecyclerView provides the `OnItemTouchListener` to handle touch events, what you would need to achieve in theory, is to create an identical item to the new recycler view and remove it from the previous one, by coding for the desired motion event. It's probably not exactly what you want, but it's the same functionalitiy in principle.

Comment: i am also stuck in that ,you got your solution?

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690522/drag-and-drop-between-two-recyclerview), it's an old question, but seems to be the same problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop between two RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690522/drag-and-drop-between-two-recyclerview)

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but no answer yet, so I provide a short one...

For dragging something from one view to another you can use the `DragShadowBuilder`. The `ItemTouchHelper` is only meant for moving items within the `RecyclerView`, you need a custom implementation for what you want.

Check out this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop (so yes, for what you want you should is this classic drag&drop framework as you called it)

It shows you how to create the shadow, how to move it (done automatically) and how to react to the drag event in the second view.

The workflow is following:

1. Create the drag shadow when e.g. long pressing an item in `RecyclerView` 1 (it's a copy of the item, drawn over the app)
2. The shadow can be moved around, handled by the framework already; this will call drag enter/exits and drag events on the views it is draggede over
3. add a `View.OnDragListener` on the second `RecyclerView` and handle the events (e.g. add the data in the second `RecyclerView` if the user drops it over it and remove it from the first `RecyclerView`)

With the help of `DragShadowBuilder` you can find tutorials on this, like e.g. the one here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by using ItemTouchHelper and OnItemTouchListener

```
        var selectedViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null

    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
        ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, 0
    ) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            val sourcePosition = source.adapterPosition
            val targetPosition = target.adapterPosition
            if (selectedViewHolder == null) {
                selectedViewHolder =
                    recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(sourcePosition)
                Collections.swap(customerList, sourcePosition, targetPosition)
                custAdapter.notifyItemMoved(sourcePosition, targetPosition)
                return true
            }
            return false

        }
        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        }
    })
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.rvCustomerList)

    binding.rvCustomerList.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(
            requireContext(),
            object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                    val childView = binding.rvCustomerList.findChildViewUnder(e!!.x,e!!.y)
                    motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(e)
                    when (e?.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            val data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
                            val shadowBuilder = DragShadowBuilder(
                                childView
                            )
                            childView!!.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0)
                            motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(e)
                          
                        }
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            childView!!.x = e.x
                            childView!!.y = e.y
                        }
                        else -> {
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
            return false
        }

        override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}

        override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
    })
```

In this rvCustomerList is the recyclerview.
Now I can move the selected item from recyclrview anywhere in the screen.

Hope this is helpful.